# How do I shrink a div using its center as reference point in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have the following div :

```
<div id = "shrink-test" style = "position:absolute;top:100px;left:50%;margin-left:-50px;height:100px;width:100px;background-color: red;" />
```

and I want to use jQuery's `animate()` to shrink the div to half of its size but keep the animation and position of my div centered.

I'm trying:

```
$("#shrink-test").animate(
{
   height: 50,
   width: 50
});
```

but it shrinks the div using its top left corner as reference. How can I make it use its center as the reference point?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What about using CSS3 `transform: scale(0.5)`? (`transform-origin` is `center` by default)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your div is positioned absolutely by using `top` and `margin-left`, you will need to animate those as well:

```
$("#shrink-test").animate({
   height: 50,
   top: 125, // 100 + 50 / 2
   width: 50,
   marginLeft: -25 // 50 / -2
});
```

For a programmatical approach it might be easier to use a negative margin for the y-axis, too.

Answer (score 4):

Here's just a simple jQuery plugin for this

```
$.fn.resize = function( w, h ) {
  w = ( undefined !== w ? w : 50 );
  h = ( undefined !== h ? h : 50 );

  var cw = this.width();
  var ch = this.height();

  if ( 'static' === this.css( 'position' ) ) {
    this.css( {
      'position'    : 'relative',
      'top'         : '0px',
      'left'        : '0px'
    } );
  }

  this.stop().width( cw ).height( ch ).animate( {
    'top'    : '+=' + ( (ch - h) / 2 ) + 'px',
    'left'   : '+=' + ( (cw - w) / 2 ) + 'px',
    'width'  : w + 'px',
    'height' : h + 'px'
  } );
};

$( function() {
  $( '#shrink-test' ).resize(50,50);
} );
```

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/bukfixart/nPjMa/1/

Answer (score 3):

You can animate top and left like so:

```
  $("#shrink-test").animate(
  {
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      top: '+=25px',
      left: '+=25px'
  });
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6Rry/2/)

Comment: hmm.. If you try the following code on Chrome's console (try it over at http://jquery.com/) : `$("body").append('<div id = "shrink-test" style = "position:absolute;top:100px;left:50%;margin-left:-50px;height:100px;width:100px;background-color: red;" />');` and once appended if you do `$("#shrink-test").animate(
  {
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      top: '+=25px',
      left: '+=25px'
  });` you'll see it's not working

Comment: This code makes the `left` value absolute, while it should stay relative.

Comment: @Bergi: You can do it with % if you prefer, but it's going to be tricky to calculate since the width is absolute (you need to figure out what % of the parent width is equivalent to 25px).

Comment: @MattBurland: I meant that it is impossible to combine relative and absolute values (at least in CSS2.1), which is requested here. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @Bergi: Far enough. Here's a [version](http://jsfiddle.net/H6Rry/3/) that calculates the appropriate %, but I think you are correct that it's probably better to use the margin instead.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to animate the position on the page at the same time using something like `top` and `left` or `margin` properties, like so:

```
$("#shrink-test").animate(
{
   height: 50,
   width: 50,
   top: '150px',
   left: '75%'
});
```

Using appropriate values for each.