# Jquery: Shrink to center and stay there

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation

I've got an element that I want to shrink, with the center as the vanishing point, to a certain percentage, and then remain there.

this is pretty close:

`$('canvas.intro').effect( "scale", { percent: 80 }, 700 );`

But it has two problems: The scale change is not retained, and the position of the element is shifted after the animation ends.

Here is a fiddle showing what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/72Xrc/

---

**Edit**

Hrm, apparently this is a bug in jquery UI: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4316.

Can anyone see a simple workaround for the `scale` effect, or a good way to achieve the same in a flexible way with a generic animation?

Comment: How about a fiddle? When is it "not retained"?

Comment: Try using the animate jquery method which allows animating multiple css properties at the same time. We can not help as to why it is not retained if you do not tell us when/how the scale is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when the black box is clicked, it should shrink to `10px * 10px` square box (you can change that) and be at a distance of `100px` from `top` and `100px` from `left` (you can change that also). If this what you need, then this is the solution.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/4N8DX/2/)

#### JS Code:

```
$('#test').on('click', function(){
    // Means within 4 seconds, change width, height to 10px and offsets to 100px
    $(this).animate({
        width:"10px",
        height:"10px",
        top:"100px",
        left:"100px"
    }, 4000);
});
```

#### EDIT:

I did some search on Google and found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203910/how-do-i-shrink-a-div-using-its-center-as-reference-point-in-jquery) and this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bukfixart/nPjMa/1/). The last answer has a plugin for exactly what you need !

Comment: Close, but the issue is this.  I need it to shrink to center (hence the `scale` effect), and when its done, I don't want to have to calculate the final position and size, since the effect already does that, and in the real app, the element can have variable position and size.

Comment: Yes!  That's it exactly.  I modified it to an onclick: http://jsfiddle.net/nPjMa/3/

Comment: @mtyson Good to see it solved the problem! Happy Coding!